How to solve the ODE $Q'=Q^2 +rQ$?
When I read a paper, seemly, the author state that
$$
Q(t) =\frac{-r e^{rt}}{e^{rt}-1}
\tag{1}
$$
solve
$$
Q'=Q^2 +rQ  
\tag{2}
$$
where $r$ is a  positive constant.  About ODE I know little, I can only solve linear ordinary differential equations. I want to know how to solve  (2). Thanks.

It’s separable.

Write the ODE as $\dfrac{dQ}{dt}=Q^2+rQ$. Then $\dfrac{dt}{dQ}=\dfrac{1}{Q(Q+r)}$.

@CalvinKhorv  Yes, Thanks. I  didn't notice it.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%28Q%28Q%2Br%29%29%2CQ%5D
